# Configuring Fault Contract Exception Handlers in Enterprise Library 6 for WCF

Tags: wcf, exception, enterprise-library

How do you map additional properties of an exception to your custom fault contract when using Enterprise Library 6's Exception Handling Application Block?

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649012.aspx) describes the FaultContractPropertyMapping the same way [this one does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff953192%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx). If you have a fault contract like so:

```
[DataContract]
public class SalaryCalculationFault
{
  [DataMember]
  public Guid FaultID { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public string FaultMessage { get; set; }
}
```

How do you add another property and map it to the original exception? Lets say I want to show the Stored Procedure name to the client using a new property:

```
[DataMember]
public string StoredProcedureName { get; set; }
```

I try editing the mapping shown on page 90 of the "Developer's Guide to Microsoft Enterprise Library-Preview.pdf" [which can be found here](https://entlib.codeplex.com/downloads/get/668950) but it does not seem to work. My new mapping looks like this:

```
var mappings = new NameValueCollection();
mappings.Add("FaultID", "{Guid}");
mappings.Add("FaultMessage", "{Message}");
mappings.Add("StoredProcedureName", "{Procedure}");   //SqlException has a Procedure property
```

And here is the policy.

```
var testPolicy = new List<ExceptionPolicyEntry>
{
    {
        new ExceptionPolicyEntry(typeof(SqlException), 
            PostHandlingAction.ThrowNewException, 
            new IExceptionHandler[]
            {
                new FaultContractExceptionHandler(typeof(SalaryCalculationFault), mappings)
            }) 
    }
};

var policies = new List<ExceptionPolicyDefinition>();
policies.Add(new ExceptionPolicyDefinition(
    "TestPolicy", testPolicy));

exManager = new ExceptionManager(policies);
ExceptionPolicy.Reset();
ExceptionPolicy.SetExceptionManager(exManager);
```

When I do this and catch the FaultException on the client and inspect it, the StoredProcedureName is always empty. Why doesn't it map from the SqlException to the new property in my fault exception?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but you would add StoredProcedureName to your Fault contract.

Comment: Yeah, my OP shows that I added a public string StoredProcedureName DataMember to the DataContract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you shouldn't actually place the code you expect an exception for inside of the ExceptionManager.Processs() method. I was doing this before:

```
exManager.Process(() => wimDAL.Execute_NonQueryNoReturn(sc), "TestPolicy");
```

Insead, just execute the code as normal.

```
wimDAL.Execute_NonQueryNoReturn(sc);
```

This does not follow what the "Developer's Guide to Microsoft Enterprise Library-Preview.pdf" says but I guess the documentation is still a work in progress. I hope this helps someone else.